# How do I specify the default button of a TextBox that is referred to by AcceptsReturn?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a windows form with a tool strip on it containing a text box and some buttons (think browser url bar with a go button, back, forward)

I want pressing enter to activate the goButton just as clicking it would, which I believe is what TextBox.AcceptsReturn = false is for.

I don't see anything that seems to fit the bill for "tell me what button on the form is the one that we will activate".

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Form` has a default button, but a specific control does not (out of the box anyway).

In your scenario, I would probably handle invoking the `goButton.Click` event by monitoring the keys pressed waiting for the Enter key to be pressed.

Comment: I'm adding a handler in my constructor (`this.myTextBox.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(urlTextBox_KeyDown);`) and added a method which checks the KeyEventArgs for the enter key.  Thanks

Comment: Rather than calling the click handler event directly I made a call to `goButton.PerformClick()`, for anyone in the future who needs more information.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to set the forms "Accept Button" to the button control you want. This can be done in the designer.

Comment: It is possible that I will have more than one text box and wish for them to activate different buttons, so while this info may be useful for the future, it doesn't solve my problem today.

Comment: Ok. Well like the others have said. This can be done in your code with the evenHandlers.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an Old Question, but for someone who might to to lazy or just a beginner ,
handler might look like too much work ( though it isn't really )

But there is an easier work around for this,
you can make a panel for each of them ( 1 Textbox and 1 Button for Example ) , and set the Defaultbutton for Each panel as you need.

I used this for my site, where I had several Ajax panel , and I Wanted Each to have their own search box on different subjects and work with Enter Button.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an old question, but I will provide my solution.

```
    private void ChangeDefaultButton()
    {
        if (this.TextBox.Focused)
        {
            this.AcceptButton = button;
        }
        else
        {
            this.AcceptButton = button1;
        }
    }
```

And then add this method to the Focus Events of the text boxes. Like...

```
    private void TextBox_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChangeDefaultButton();
    }
```

And

```
    private void TextBox_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChangeDefaultButton();
    }
```